# Trying all possibilities for a number grid

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, grid

I'm trying to solve a maths problem programmatically. I have a 6x5 grid, with a few predefined numbers, and I have to find the rest of the numbers with the condition of all rows and columns should total 34.

//Grid

[image]

```
    static int[][] sq;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        sq = new int[6][];

        for (int i = 0; i < sq.Length; i++)
        {
            sq[i] = new int[5] { -250, -250, -250, -250, -250, };
        }

        SetDefaults();

        Print();

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void SetDefaults()
    {
        sq[0][0] = 7;
        sq[0][1] = 6;
        sq[0][2] = 8;

        sq[2][2] = 9;
        sq[2][3] = 8;
        sq[2][4] = 5;

        sq[3][1] = 9;
        sq[3][3] = 7;
        sq[3][4] = 5;

        sq[4][0] = 4;
        sq[4][1] = 4;
        sq[4][4] = 9;

        sq[5][0] = 8;
        sq[5][2] = 3;
        sq[5][3] = 6;
        sq[5][4] = 8;
    }

    static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i<sq.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < sq[i].Length; ii++)
            {
                Console.Write("[" + sq[i][ii] + "\t]");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

I think one method is try all the possibilities, with a range of 500 numbers, from -250 to 250, or an incremental range (-1,1, then -2,2, etc), but I don't know how to do this programmatically and much less efficiently.

Comment: Why -250 to 250? Is that a specification of the task? The numbers look as if they are all positive.

Comment: Unless you have a problem with the code then I'm pretty sure this is off topic for SO. You want http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ because your question is about "algorithm and data structure concepts", something that is [on topic](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for programmers stack exchange.

Comment: @NicoSchertler No, -250,250 is one range i think is enough extense to fit the solution, but is not mandatory. The negative numbers are because if I try to solve this exercise by hand, appear a lot of negative numbers. Thx!

Comment: Well, if you allow negative numbers, then you will get an infinite number of solutions because it will always be possible to increment/decrement a set of numbers without changing the sums.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Any solution is valid. I started to use negative numbers because really I don't know if a solution can be reached with positive numbers only. Of course, the best is a solution with positive numbers like the grid ones.

Comment: @m69 I only have the picture...

Comment: So all the numbers added up equal both 5x34 (columns) and 6x34 (rows) ? How is that possible?

Comment: @m69 Good observation. This is probably what the task aimed for.

Comment: @m69 I don't understand what are you saying. Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: There is no solution to this puzzle. If you add up all the rows, you get the sum of all the values, and that's supposed to be 6x34 = 204. If you add up all the columns, you get the sum of all the values, and that's supposed to be 5x34 = 170. So either it's a trick question, or it was a 6x6 grid and they forgot to print one of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a 6x5 grid

The number of columns and rows is different?
**Then, no matter what's in the grid, there is no solution at all to make all sums equal. Consequently there is nothing to code.**

Not putting too much effort in it, but if you are really thinking of enumerating something, you could (but shouldn't) try this naive and unoptimized approach (for a range of integers between 0 and 15):

```
for (int a = 0; a < 16; a++) {
for (int b = 0; b < 16; b++) {
for (int c = 0; c < 16; c++) {
for (int d = 0; d < 16; d++) {
for (int e = 0; e < 16; e++) {
for (int f = 0; f < 16; f++) {
for (int g = 0; g < 16; g++) {
for (int h = 0; h < 16; h++) {
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
for (int l = 0; l < 16; l++) {
for (int m = 0; m < 16; m++) {
for (int n = 0; n < 16; n++) {
// test all columns and rows:
// test if 7 + 8 + 9 + a + b == 34
// test if c + d + e + f + g == 34
...
}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

Certainly possible to optimize a lot, like:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 16; a++) {
var b = 34 - 7 - 8 - 9 - a;
for (int c = 0; c < 16; c++) {
for (int d = 0; d < 16; d++) {
for (int e = 0; e < 16; e++) {
for (int f = 0; f < 16; f++) {
var g = 34 - c - d - e - f;
for (int h = 0; h < 16; h++) {
var i = 34 - 9 - 8 - 5 - h;
for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
var k = 34 - 9 - 7 - 5 - j;
for (int l = 0; l < 16; l++) {
var m = 34 - 4 - 4 - 9 - l;
var n = 34 - 8 - 3 - 6 - 8;
// test all columns only:
// test if 7 + c + h + 4 + 8 == 34
...
}}}}}}}}
```

But in the end, best optimization is to return "no solution" directly.